# How to line up variable-length underscore lines on web page?

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF to display some table data.  For that, I use HTML + CSS, which is then converted to PDF form.  I want to have underline lines in my table, where people can write-in notes.  I currently use the underline character `_` to draw these lines.  The problem I seem to have is that they are jagged on the right hand side (see exaggerated image below). 
[image]

I am looking for a way to not have the lines be jagged.  In reality I can make them less jagged but due to non-fixed-width fonts, they still appear a little jagged, even if I add/remove the underline characters to try to line them up.

I am looking for any reasonable solution where underlines line up to the right border of table/div/container.  This can be done any way (using chars or CSS, or maybe even images), as long as things line up properly.  In my case the container is `<td>words words _____</td>`

Something like this:
[image]

**Note / Update :**

Unfortunately, after trying answers below I found out that TCPDF is not very robust or forgiving when it comes CSS markup that is a little more than basic.  The solutions below while work on browsers, did not seem to survive the HTML+CSS to {PDF through TCPDF} converter.  I am not sure if a solution is possible given the state of TCPDF development, at least for the free version. I may have to stick with uneven underline chars for now.

Comment: The question lacks a clear problem statement. Do you really want to use sequences of underline characters, or are you looking for a good rendering of a table? In the latter case, you should probably consider using borders between cells instead of underline character tricks. Showing some actual HTML and CSS code would help, especially if accompanied with a description of how the result differs from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution that uses `bottom-border` to achieve the underline.

```
.container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    padding: 1rem;
}

p {
    border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}

span {
    border-bottom: solid purple 3px;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
```

and

```
<div class="container">
    <p><span>Question thingy</span></p>
    <p><span>Question thingy asdf </span></p>
    <p><span>Question thingy asdf asdf asdf  </span></p>
</div>
```

It produces this output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I like this way, pure and simple.  Unfortunately turns out the CSS/HTML I put in, is run through some proprietary software (it is translated to a PDF), ant the software does not render border-bottom correctly.  I may have to stick to underlines for now.  But I learned something cool!

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to give you great advice without seeing your existing markup, but hopefully this will point you in the right direction: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4w49/). Basically, we have a full width line to fake the underline, then our text has a white background to cover up the line beneath it.

Example HTML:

```
<p><span>Text</span></p>
<p><span>Longer text</span></p>
<p><span>Even longer text</span></p>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    position: relative;
}

p:after {
    background: #000;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute; bottom: 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

span {
    background: #fff;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thought occurred to me ...

perhaps instead of focusing on making lines consistent I can change my design.  i.e. use a table similar to that of Excel sheet.

```
 _________________
|_words__|________|  <-- empty cells instead 
|_words2_|________|      of underlines
```

TCPDF seems to deal okay with those.